# Open ngx-smart-modal without disabling the background?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 2 `ngx-smart-modals` that I am using to for adding a few features in my application. The first one contains a form and on clicking the "Add" button, a new modal opens up containing the recently added data from the form. something like this:
[image: Picture]

(The modal "Beh" is the second modal that pop's up, "beh" is just a dummy text for now, and the positioning also needs to be changed so please ignore that for now :) )

The problem that I have is that When I click "Add", the modal "Beh" disables the form at the background, but I want it to still be enabled for adding more data.

Is there any property or a method that would help me achieve this? Something to disable the invisible layer on top of the form?

My code:

**detail component (the "beh" one)**:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgxSmartModalComponent } from 'ngx-smart-modal';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-detail-modal',
  templateUrl: './detail-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./detail-modal.component.scss']
})
export class DetailModalComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('detailModal') public detailModal: NgxSmartModalComponent;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.detailModal.dismissable = false;
    this.detailModal.backdrop = false;
    this.detailModal.escapable = false;
    this.detailModal.isVisible();
  }

  resetData() {
   // this.detailModal.setData(window.localStorage['feature']);
  }

}
```

**create modal (the form)**:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslatePipe } from 'src/app/pipes/translate/translate.pipe';
import { DynamicTextFieldService } from 'src/app/services/dynamic-loading/dynamic-text-field/dynamic-text-field.service';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { DynamicDropdownService } from 'src/app/services/dynamic-loading/dynamic-dropdown/dynamic-dropdown.service';
import { featureMeta, platform } from 'src/app/components/modals/create-feature-modal/featureMeta';
import { DynamicTextAreaService } from 'src/app/services/dynamic-loading/dynamic-text-area/dynamic-text-area.service';
import { NgxSmartModalComponent, NgxSmartModalService } from 'ngx-smart-modal';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-feature-modal',
  templateUrl: './create-feature-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-feature-modal.component.scss']
})

/**
* This class creates a featureModal component
*/
export class CreateFeatureModalComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit {

  /*constructor and other methods*/

  /**
  * initialize buildForm
  */
  ngOnInit() {
    this.buildForm();
  }


  /**
  * Add data (this is the opening function for the modal)
  */
  addData() {
    this.ngxsmartmodal.getModal('detailModal').open();
  }
```

**template for form**:

```
<app-detail-modal></app-detail-modal>
<ngx-smart-modal #featureModal [identifier]="'featureModal'">
  <h2 Align="center">{{"views[modal][feature][heading]" | translate }}</h2>
  <form [formGroup]="featureForm">
    <div #name class='feature'></div>
    <div #type class='feature'></div>
    <div #platform class='feature'></div>
    <div #detail class='feature'></div>
    <app-button description="{{ 'views[modal][feature][button][submit]' | translate }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-md submit" (callFunction)="setData()"></app-button>
    <app-button description="{{ 'views[modal][feature][button][add]' | translate }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-md submit" (callFunction)="addData()"></app-button>
    <app-button description="{{ 'views[modal][feature][button][cancel]' | translate }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-md cancel" (callFunction)="featureModal.close()"></app-button>
  </form>
</ngx-smart-modal>
```

**template for detailcomponent**:

```
<ngx-smart-modal #detailModal [identifier]="'detailModal'" (onOpen)="resetData()">
  <div *ngIf="detailModal.hasData()">
    <h3>Beh</h3>
  </div>
</ngx-smart-modal>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is default and expected behavior of modals.

see this definition of modal window user Interface

> [In user interface design for computer applications, a modal window is
>   a graphical control element subordinate to an application's main
>   window. It creates a mode that disables the main window but keeps it
>   visible, with the modal window as a child window in front of it. Users
>   must interact with the modal window before they can return to the
>   parent application.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window)

your requirement is not creating a second modal but

1. If you want to only display some text or images on second popup use
   Toast Message
2. If you want to add second form place both on same modal.
3. If you want something else let me know.